# Change output of function object to state its name

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

I am trying to do some basic lambda calculus in Javascript and I am using Node as REPL. I define the identity and mockinbird combinator and run the mockingbird combinator with the identity combinator as input.

```
I = f => f
M = f => f(f)
M(I)
```

The mockinbird combinator with the identity combinator as input yields the identity combinator. The last line gives the following output.

```
[Function]
```

But it would be more useful, in this case, if it outputted something like the following.

```
[Function: I]
```

This way I can see what function is being printed. I have seen this done in this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VQ382QG-y4

Does anybody have any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: What version of Node are you using? It works fine for me on 8.4.0: http://i.imgur.com/2WnMYOz.png

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of node.js do this already (at least v6+, maybe earlier). If you don't want to upgrade, then you could define an inspect method, which node.js will use when inspecting:

```
Function.prototype.inspect = function () {
  return "[Function: " + this.name + "]";
}
```